# byte[] to file in the internal storage

Tags: android

After a WebService call, I have a `byte[]`.
I would like to convert this in a file (**diapo.mp4**) in the **INTERNAL STORAGE** only.

My code is not working because the app don't pass the `try`. Why ?

This is my code :

```
@Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] binaryData) {
    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(binaryData);
    try {
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("diapo.mp4");
        byte data[] = new byte[4096];
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
              output.write(data, 0, count);
              }
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After a WebService call, I have a byte[]. I would like to convert this in a file (diapo.mp4) in the INTERNAL STORAGE only.

It is unlikely that you have sufficient contiguous heap space for a `byte[]` for a meaningful video file.

> My code is not working because the app don't pass the try

If you look at LogCat and examine the Java stack trace, you will find that it is complaining that it cannot write to that location. `new FileOutputStream("diapo.mp4")` points nowhere.

Create a `File` object pointing to an actual location, using a method to get the desired root directory, whether on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) (e.g., `new File(getFilesDir(), "diapo.mp4")`) or on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) (e.g., `new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "diapo.mp4")`).